# How fast can one compute the power of a number?

Tags: time-complexity, runtime-analysis, polynomial-time, arithmetic, modular-arithmetic

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \cup \{0\}$ then how fast can one compute $x^k$?

---

If $x, k \in  \mathbb{Z}$ then I guess this previous discussion already settled that, [How many operations at maximum needed to compute powering of a number, i.e. $N^k$?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/49016/how-many-operations-at-maximum-needed-to-compute-powering-of-a-number-i-e-nk)

Comment: What is your model of real computation?

Comment: Those are the things that are not clear to me :) It would be great if you could kindly explain! For a specific purpose I have in mind you can as well assume that $x$ is being obtained as the inner product of two d-dimensional real vectors of bounded norm.

Comment: I suggest you do some reading first on the area. There are at least two or three different models. If I remember correctly there is a list somewhere on cstheory.

Answer (score 1):

There are several methods given in wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring.

If both $x,k \in \mathbb{R}$, then you can compute $x^k$ as $e^{k  \log x}$ as there are somewhat efficient algorithms for $e^x$ and $\log x$.